# Find the area of the given curve. $y = 7x^2, y = 4 + 6x^2$

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the given curve. $y = 7x^2,  y = 4 + 6x^2$

[image]

Comment: Find the points of the intersections between the two curves, then the area is the integral of  the upper curve minus the lower curve, where your limits of integration are the x coordinates of the two intersecting points.

Comment: The title and the body of the question are asking two different things. In any case, what work have you done on it?

Comment: $$Area = \int\limits_A {dA}  = \int\limits_{{x_1}}^{{x_2}} {\int\limits_{{y_1}}^{{y_2}} {dydx} }  = \int\limits_{ - 2}^2 {\int\limits_{7{x^2}}^{4 + 6{x^2}} {dydx} } $$

Comment: I have solved the following equation $\displaystyle \int_{-2}^2 ((4+6x^2)-7x^2)dx$ my answer is $\frac{32}{3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two curves intersect at two points $x = \pm 2$, thus the area is:
$\displaystyle \int_{-2}^2 ((4+6x^2)-7x^2)dx$

Comment: Is the area under the cover $\frac{32}{3}$?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Yes that's correct. You can always use Wolfram Alpha to double check a simple integral though instead of asking anyone to verify your work.